# WCF Rest upload file size issue

Tags: c#, wcf, rest

Initially, my upload was limited to 64KB.

I have gone through multiple suggestions on web and on this site, and made following changes

```
 <bindings>
  <webHttpBinding>
    <binding name="StreamedRequestWebBinding"
             maxReceivedMessageSize="10485760"
maxBufferPoolSize="10485760" maxBufferSize="10485760" closeTimeout="00:03:00"
openTimeout="00:03:00" receiveTimeout="00:10:00" sendTimeout="00:03:00">
      <readerQuotas maxDepth="32" maxStringContentLength="10485760"
maxArrayLength="10485760" maxBytesPerRead="10485760" />
      <security mode="None" />
    </binding>
  </webHttpBinding>
</bindings>

<endpoint address="" bindingConfiguration="StreamedRequestWebBinding" behaviorConfiguration="web" binding="webHttpBinding"
      contract="DatingService.IRegisterService1" />

 <system.web>
<compilation debug="true" targetFramework="4.0" />
<httpRuntime executionTimeout="240" maxRequestLength="10240" />
<pages validateRequest="false" />

  </system.web>
```

After making above changes, I am able to upload max of 4MB, though I have given max allowed size to 10MB. We havent ported application to IIS yet, and testing from visual studio only. Where did I go wrong? Pl suggest

Comment: Try increasing your maxItemsInObjectGraph property. Also i guess the above is your server side config entry. Do you have the same readerQuotas and httRuntime maxRequestLenght properties set on the client side as well?

Answer (score -1):

4mb is a default max post size for the application server. You can change this

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/e1f13641(v=vs.71).aspx

Comment: I tried that.Forgot to include in my Q. Added my settings. Thanks!